# css: two columns of divs

Tags: css, html, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 columns div for ie8 and ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280456/2-columns-div-for-ie8-and-ie7)

in my website, I need to add inside a `<div>` (the black square, which is sort of a container) two columns of `<div>`s. you can understand it more easily from the drawing I attached.

it should:

1. support major browsers (Explorer 6 **not** needed)
2. be relatively simple
3. change the space size between the two columns, easily.
4. change the `<div>`s horizonal position.

Much thanks.  [image: sketch]

Comment: I know the table element is really hated, but If you want to display tabular data (not for design), use a table.

Comment: Please provide the HTML.  The solution depends on the source order of your elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
#black {height:600px;width:500px;border:2px solid #000000;}
#black div{height:80px;width:150px;margin-top:20px;}
.green {border:2px solid #009900;float:left;margin-left:60px;}
.red{border: 2px solid #FF0000;float:right;margin-right:60px;}
</style>

   <div id="black">
        <div class="green"></div> <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div> <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div> <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div> <div class="red"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box col1"></div>
    <div class="box col2"></div>
    <div class="box col1"></div>
    <div class="box col2"></div>
    <div class="box col1"></div>
    <div class="box col2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width:100%; padding: 50px; border:2px solid #000; float: left;}
.box {width:100px;height:100px;margin: 10px;}
.col1 {border:2px solid red;float:left;clear:left;}
.col2 {border:2px solid green;float:left;}
```

Modify the **.box** padding to change the space size between the two columns

Modify the **.container** padding to change the  horizonal position for the columns inside the container.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reB7v/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
 <style>           
        .outer{width:100%; padding: 20px; border:1px solid #000; float: left;}
        .red{width: 20%; height: 40px; border:2px solid red; float: left;  margin: 20px;}
        .green{width: 20%; height: 40px; border:2px solid green; float: left; margin: 20px;}
         .clear{clear:both;}
    </style>

     <div class="outer">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

nesting columns could be devided into Grid system and Fluid grid system.
You can get info from [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and copy its nesting columns CSS.